# What is the cause of this failure to make a SCSS mixin with an optional parameter?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I need a SCSS mixin to make borders with. In this mixin, the `$position` variable, should be optional:

```
@mixin border($position, $width, $style, $color) {
  @if $position {
    border-#{$position}: $width $style $color;
  } @else {
    border: $width $style $color;
  }
}
```

This is necessary so that I can use it in these 2 types of cases:

```
.box {
   @include border('bottom', 1px, solid, #999) /*with position*/;
}
```

and

```
.button {
    @include border(1px, solid, #999); /*without position*/
    @include border-radius(9999999px);
    padding: .5rem .75rem;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

For the second case, the compiler throws the error:

```
Mixin border is missing argument $color.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default parameter for $position. I used the `false` boolean for default variable.

```
@mixin border($width, $style, $color, $position: false) {
  @if $position {
    border-#{$position}: $width $style $color;
  } @else {
    border: $width $style $color;
  }
}
```

And you can use like this:

```
.button {
  @include border(1px, solid, #999);
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

If you don't send any parameter, it enters else state (like above). If you send a position parameter, it enters the if state. Like this:

```
.button {
  @include border(1px, solid, #999, right);
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that optional parameters must come after mandatory parameters. This is a rule.